# Stuck at Integrating Multiple Django databases

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django but can't seem to find my way around this challenge. 
Scene:
I have a new Django project I want to use as an API I have my default database setup and works perfectly when I try to view the tables in my admin panel (Only table present is the user's table)

So I have another database that I want to integrate into the project. It's populated already and I won't be writing data into it just reading data from it.

I have been able to add the database to my database list in settings.py, I have also run inspectdb and my models have been generated i have done my migrations and i can view the model objects from shell command.

**Challenge**

So i have the models registered in my admin.py file and I can find the two generated tables in the admin panel when i login but when i try to click on it to view it gives me an error that the table doesn't exist. I was able to deduce the problem to be that when i try to open any of those two generated tables in the admin panel, Django searches for those tables in the default database instead of the legacy database.

Solutions i have tried

I actually tried using routers.py but i guess i couldn't get the proper syntax considering the fact that I'm using just a single app but multiple databases it's just driving me crazy honestly

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'thelwk_rest',
        'USER': 'webmaster',
        'PASSWORD':'**************',
        'HOST':'10.01.01.01',
        'PORT':'3306',
    },
    'lwkdata': {
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':'thelwk_data',
        'USER':'webmaster',
        'PASSWORD':'**************',
        'HOST':'10.01.01.01',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

```
tinker = Trends.objects.using('lwkdata').get(id=72)
#gives me my desired results
```

**My admin.py settings**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from profiles_api import models
from profiles_api import models2


admin.site.register(models.UserProfile)
admin.site.register(models2.ThelwkRestNtflx)
admin.site.register(models2.Trends)
```

**The error i get when i try to open the table in admin panel**

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/profiles_api/trends/
(1146, "Table 'thelwk_rest.trends' doesn't exist")
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/profiles_api/trends/
```

Comment: What did you try when using a database router?

Comment: All the use cases didn't really fit my scenario and i didnt know how to integrate it into my challenge.. The DB router examples i found had to do with if the request is coming from this app, use this DB. But in my case its just one app I'm using.. Please let me know if I'm missing something

Comment: Sounds like you have more than one app, you mentioned the "user's" table so I suspect you are using `django.contrib.auth`?

Answer (score 0):

A database router like the following would force all reads and writes for your app to be routed to your other DB:

```
class ProfilesAPIRouter:
    
    APP_LABEL = 'profiles_api'  # I think this is the name of your app
    DB_ALIAS = 'lwkdata'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == self.APP_LABEL:
            return self.DB_ALIAS
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == self.APP_LABEL:
            return self.DB_ALIAS
        return None
```

`allow_relation` and `allow_migrate` can also be overridden, although since you have used `inspectdb` to create your models I assume that they are not managed

Comment: This answer works but not for my scenario but i was able to use it to create my router as it gave me a clearer understanding of how django routers work.
What i needed was to be able to view my tables in the admin panel and there is no way to explicitly define the db for admin panel to use. So this was the link i followed to solve the problem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#exposing-multiple-databases-in-django-s-admin-interface

Comment: I upvoted your answer but it won't appear as I have a low reputation or whatever stack calls it. Thanks for taking the time once more.